# Delete line regex is found on

Tags: regex, tcl

I am looking to iterate through a file, finding certain patterns, if that pattern is found, removing the entire line it is on.

This is currently what I have:

```
#  Slurp up the data files
set fp [open "params.txt" r]
set file_data [read $fp]
close $fp

set fp [open [lindex $argv 0] r ]
set configFile [read $fp] 
close $fp

#  Process data file
set data [split $file_data "\n"]
    foreach line $data {

    # do some line processing here
    if { "$data" != "" } { 

        if { [ regexp {\b"$data"\b} $configFile ] == 1 } {
            #Remove entire line regex is found on in $configFile
        }
    }
}
#write $configFile to a file
```

The script is going to have only one argument, which will be the "haystack," params.txt is a hardcoded list of "needles."  My issue is that the regex returns true or false, so I don't know how to get to the proper line, and then remove the whole thing.

*What makes it trickier is that most of the items in params.txt are "words" that are inside things I do not wish to delete (example below)*

```
apple starts with "a"
applepie is delicious
pineapple is delicious
```

I want to delete the line `apple starts with "a"` but no touch the others. I say "words" because I also have things like `get parameters` as a "word" I want to find and remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that the words in `params.txt` are just letters (+ maybe digits and underscores, i.e., not RE metasyntax), one per line, then we can do this with:

```
# Read in config
set fp [open "params.txt"]
set words [split [read $fp] "\n"]
close $fp

# Read in data
set fp [open "inputData.txt"]
set lines [read $fp]
close $fp

# Process it all
foreach word $words {
    regsub -all -line "^.*\\y$word\\y.*(?:\n|$)" $lines "" lines
}

# Write out
set fp [open "outputData.txt" w]
puts -nonewline $fp $lines
close $fp
```

The real key to this is this:

```
regsub -all -line "^.*\\y$word\\y.*(?:\n|$)" $lines "" lines
```

The interesting bits are:

- `-line`, which puts `regsub` in line-matching mode instead of the default “whole string matching” mode (affecting how `^`, `.` and `$` work),
- `-all`, which makes `regsub` replace all possible matches instead of just the first one,
- `\\y`, which is `\y` to the RE engine, and which matches a word boundary, and
- `(?:\n|$)` which matches the newline at the end *or* the end of the string/line, so the line is removed and not just cleared.

---

If each line in the config is more general than that, you need to do some extra work to make it “nice” before using it in `regsub`. Fortunately, `regsub` is the right tool for it!

```
foreach word $words {
    # I'm trimming the lines; you might want to not do that...
    regsub -all {\W} [string trim $word] {\\&} subRE
    regsub -all -line "^.*\\y$subRE\\y.*(?:\n|$)" $lines "" lines
}
```

Comment: This is much more in line with what I was doing! My current solution was `[regsub {.*\y$line\y.*} $configFile "" $configFile]` but I was having issues matching. I'll try this, thanks!

Comment: It works! Mostly... I forgot that I do have some rather obnoxious data in there, like linux commands: `wget -q -O /dev/null --http-user=admin --http-passwd=PASS http://192.168.1.6 http://192.168.1.6 http://192.168.1.6/T4 http://192.168.1.6/L`

That's no fault of yours, of course. I simply forgot to include it. You've given me a good start though!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this,

```
.*\bapple\b.*
```

It would match the line which contains an exact word `apple`. Just deleting the matched line will give you the desired result.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eY1pO0)

Comment: Oh my god you're totally right. It's pretty obvious I haven't touched regex in a few months. Wouldn't that find literally the entire file though?

Comment: @Joshua added demo part for your clarification.

Comment: Hmmm thanks. Could you explain why that is the case? Does \b add some kind of newline break case I'm not aware of?

Comment: `\b` means a word boundary. The meaning of word boudary is, it matches between a word character and a non word character.These are called word characters, [a-zA-Z0-9_] and all the others are non word character. So space comes under non word character, and the apple starts with a word character thus matching the exact string apple.

Comment: TCL uses \y not \b! Good to know.

Comment: Theoretically it does, but I'm not sure what weird differences TCL has, because in practice it's not working. I've altered your demo to have my dataset and it works, but not in the actual script.

Comment: Tcl's RE language is [definitively documented in `re_syntax(n)`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), part of its documentation tree.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
#  Slurp up the data files
set fp [open "params.txt" r]
set fileData [split [read -nonewline $fp] \n]
close $fp

set fp [open [lindex $argv 0] r ]
set configData [split [read -nonewline $fp] \n]
close $fp

#  Process data file
foreach line $fileData {
    set configData [lsearch -not -all -inline -regexp "\\m$line\\M" $configData]
}
```

Use -nonewline so you don't get a "false" blank line after the split.
I prefer `\m` and `\M` to be explicit about start and end of word.
Since you need to substitute the variable, the regex needs to be in double quotes, and you need to double the backslashes.

http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lsearch.htm
http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M72